# Elasticsearch version 5.0.1 , search analyse isn't working.

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. We are using Elasticsearch 5.0.1, I am trying to create an index, like below. I did go through the documentation of Elastic search and some of the posts here, but not able to create an index with the below-desired settings

```
 PUT testv2 
 {
     "settings": {
         "index": {
            "number_of_shards": "5",

        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "nGram_filter": {
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit",
                        "punctuation",
                        "symbol"
                    ],
                    "min_gram": "2",
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "max_gram": "20"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "nGram_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "nGram_filter"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                },
                "whitespace_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                },
                "autocomplete": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                },
                "analyzer_startswith": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "keyword"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "autosuggest_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1"

    }
},
"mappings": {
    "sample": {
        "_all": {
            "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer"
        },
        "properties": {
            "sample_description": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "sample_type": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": true
            },
            "sample": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": true,
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith"
            },
            "sample1": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": true,
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But I am getting the below error, could you help me solve this, please.

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [{
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Mapping definition for [sample1] has unsupported parameters:  [search_analyzer : analyzer_startswith] [analyzer : autocomplete]"
        }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [sample]: Mapping definition for [sample1] has unsupported parameters:  [search_analyzer : analyzer_startswith] [analyzer : autocomplete]",
    "caused_by": {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Mapping definition for [sample1] has unsupported parameters:  [search_analyzer : analyzer_startswith] [analyzer : autocomplete]"
    }
},
"status": 400
 }
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, having an ngram analyzer on `_all_` is bad practice.  Its going to result in an excessive amount of tokens being created.  Also, _all_ is deprecated in version 6 so rather don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The `keyword` type doesn't support analyzers. Change the type to `text` and you should be good to go.